# How do I change the display color depth in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, display, color-depth

I want to change the display from 32-bit color-depth to 16-bit.
Changing the color depth in Windows XP was easy, but it appears that Microsoft removed the option or moved it to some hidden, advanced setting in Windows 7 and later. Does anyone know where this setting is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Does anyone know where this setting is?

1. "Start" > "Control Panel" > "Display" > "Screen Resolution".
2. Click "Advanced settings".

   > [image]
3. Select the "Monitor" tab.
4. Choose "High Color (16 Bit)" in the "Colors" popdown.

   > [image]
5. Click "OK".
6. Click "OK" a second time.

Answer (score 1):

@DavidPostill's answer is great. But, it may not work on VirtualBox. I'm posting this for those who came here, like I did, looking for an answer, but found that it didn't work in VirtualBox.

### How to Change Color to 32-Bit in VirtualBox Windows 7 Guest OS:

1. Select the Advanced Settings, as described by DavidPostill.
2. Click on the **Adapter** tab.
3. Click the **List All Modes** button, bottom left.
4. This is the key: ***You must select one of the 32-bit modes*** to be able to do the next step.

[image: Choose one of the 32-Bit modes]

5. In my system, 1280 by 960, True Color (32-bit), 60 Hz is the best setting
6. Select **OK** to close out of the **List All Modes** selection window
7. Now, if you click into the monitor tab, you should see that "True Color (32-bit)" is already selected.

I hope this has been helpful.

[image: Screenshot showing all relevant windows open simultaneously]